# "Nice" form/bounds for $\ln\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{x_i^2}{n}\right)$

Tags: approximation, closed-form, upper-lower-bounds

Does the expression

$$\ln\prod_{i = 1}^n\left(1 + \frac{x_i^2}{n}\right)$$

have either

1. a "nicer" closed-form, or
2. quantitative upper/lower bounds on such a form?

For me, "nice" essentially means "simple functions of $n, \lVert \vec x\rVert_2$".
As an example, one can write

$$\ln\prod_{i = 1}^n\left(1 + \frac{x_i^2}{n}\right) = \frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2}{n} + O(1/n^2)$$

I would say this is a qualitative "nice" approximation of my function (to first-order in $n$, where $O(\cdot)$ tracks dependency on $n$, but not $x_i$).
I'm interested if this can be made quantitative, and in particular if the dependency on $\lVert\vec x\rVert_2$ can be tracked in the error term $O(1/n^2)$, and there can be no implicit constants.

Comment: What is $x_i$ supposed to be? Also, what is $\lVert \vec x\rVert_2$? (I think the second question is obvious but I've never seen it before).

Comment: Have you tried applying Taylor's theorem with remainder to each of the summands in $\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+\frac{x_i^2}n)$, using the function $f(t) = \ln(1+t)$ near $t=0$?

Comment: @GregMartin I've mostly been playing around with inequalities from [here](https://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf). With this I can get an upper bound of $\frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2}{n}$ (with no error), which is "nice" for me. It can also give me a lower bound of $\frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2/n}{1 + \lVert x\rVert_2^2/n}$, but this does not seem to be within $O(1/n^2)$ of my upper bound.

Comment: I should phrase that less indirectly: I recommend that you try that specific approach with Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

One can prove the bounds

$$
\frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2}{n} - \frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^4}{2n^2} \leq \ln\prod_j(1+\frac{x_j^2}{n}) \leq \frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2}{n},
$$
e.g. "nice" in the way I wanted.
This is done by chaining together some [standard inequalities](https://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf).
For the upper bound, write

$$
\ln\prod_j(1+\frac{x_j^2}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}\ln\prod_j(1+\frac{x_j^2}{n})^n \leq \frac{1}{n} \ln\prod_j\exp(x_j^2) = \frac{1}{n}\ln\exp(\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2) = \frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2}{n}.
$$

For the lower bound, note that

$$\prod_j(1+\frac{x_j^2}{n})\geq 1 + \frac{\lVert \vec x\rVert_2^2}{n}$$

Combined with the bound $\ln(1+x)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\geq 0$, one gets the bound that I claimed above.